# RxJava 2 : Multiple Observers not receiving from single Observable

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm creating an observable which multiple observers subscribe to. But, i see only one of observers onNext getting called. What am i doing wrong here.

```
        private Observable<String> getDataEmitter(String downloadFileName) {

           ObservableOnSubscribe<String> handler = emitter -> {
             String file = download(downloadFileName);
             if (file == null) {
               emitter.onError(e);
             }
             String[] tokens = file.split("\\n");
             for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
               emitter.onNext(token);
             }
             emitter.onComplete();
          };

          return Observable.create(handler);
        }

       public retrieve(String file) {

         final Observable<String> sourceObservable = getDataEmitter(file) 
          .flatMap(id -> {
            return Observable.from(service.find(id))
          }, Pair::of)
          .map(pair -> collect(request, pair));


         sourceObservable
           .flatMap(this::map)
           .map(this::fileFormat)
           .buffer(10)
           .subscribe(batched -> {
             System.out.println("b-1");
           }, err -> {
             System.out.println("error-1");
           },
           () -> {
             System.out.println("completed-1");
           });

        sourceObservable
          .map(pair -> format(pair))
          .subscribe(e -> {
            System.out.println("e-2" +e);
          },
          error -> System.out.println(error-2),
          () -> System.out.println("completed-2"));
        }
```

The output is only from the first subscription. which is,

```
b-1
completed-1
```

why is it not printing for the second subscription? 
I tried using publish with connect and even replay. But, it did not help. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Just for the test purpose, Have you tried writing second observable first. It is giving the e-2 in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Your observable has terminated on `.buffer(10)` because `buffers` collects 10 emissions from a source observable and emits the entire it as a batched object,  once the source Observable terminates ([see the documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)). You aren't going to observe any more emissions from it.